# How to print the following pattern left sided right angle triangle | Python |

Tags: python

I want to print the below pattern

```
* 
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
```

I have a below logic which prints the desired output as expected in above
Is it a right approach to print the pattern. Any other approach / unique trick to get the output

```
for row in range(1,6):
  for col in range(1,6):
    if row is col:
      print(row * '* ')
```

Comment: This question is more suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The only *correctness* issue I see is that you `is` does not mean "equal", and should not be used to compare integers. Here it only works by accident because your numbers are small, due to an implementation detail.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel : if i make it like this :  `if row == col:`  is it a right way

Comment: That said, *logically* your code is strange. You should try to talk through, in plain English words, how you intend for it to work, step by step; then talk through, in plain English words, what you think the existing code actually means. You should notice something rather strange about the code's approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the second for loop, just print your line directly:

```
for row in range(1,6):
  print(row * '* ')
```

Comment: can you share the entire code

Comment: cool bro thanks for the improvement